# Find linear map matrix in basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

linear transformation in the basis $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}$ has a matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1   & 2 & 0 & 1\\
    3 & 0   & -1 & 2\\
    2 & 5  & 3 & 1\\
    1 & 2  & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find that linear map matrix in basis:

$e_{1}, e_{1} + e_{2}, e_{1} + e_{2} + e_{3},e_{1} + e_{2} + e_{3}+  e_{4}$

I tried some calculations, but answers didn't match:

I get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1   & 3 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 3   & 2 & 4\\
    2 & 7 & 10 & 11\\
    1 & 3 & 4 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

But its wrong answer. The right one is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    -2   & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & -4  & -8 & -7\\
    1 & 4  & 6 & 4\\
    1 & 3 & 4 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about the calculations that you tried?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i added comments about it

Comment: You neglected to convert the coordinates of the images of the new basis into that basis.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of a transformation matrix are the coordinates of the images of the basis vectors *relative to that basis*. It looks like you added up the appropriate columns of the original matrix to find the images of the new basis vectors, but that gets you coordinates relative to the original basis. You need to convert those coordinates to the new basis, i.e., the correct matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1&3&3&4\\3&3&2&4\\2&7&10&11\\1&3&4&7\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can find the matrix of the transformation relative to the new basis one column at a time. For example, to find the second column, we see what $T$ does to the second vector of the new basis. We have
$$
T(e_1+e_2) = T(e_1) + T(e_2) = \\
(e_1 + 3e_2 + 2e_3 + e_4) + (2e_1 + 5e_3 + 2e_4) = \\
3e_1 + 3e_2 + 7e_3 + 3e_4 = \\
0e_1 - 4(e_1 + e_2) + 4(e_1 + e_2 + e_3)+ 3(e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_4).
$$
So, the matrix of the transformation relative to the new basis is given by
$$
\pmatrix{
?&0&?&?\\
?&-4&?&?\\
?&4&?&?\\
?&3&?&?}.
$$
Note that going from the third line above to the last line requires that we solve a system of equations. In this case, however, the system is easy to solve directly.

---

We can compute this matrix using matrix-multiplication as follows. Note that the matrix
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1}
$$
is a change of basis matrix from the new basis $\mathcal B_2$ to our starting basis $\mathcal B_1 = \{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$. With that, we find that to find the matrix of the transformation represented by $M$ relative to the new basis, we compute $P^{-1}MP$.  That is, our solution will be 
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1}^{-1}
\pmatrix{    1   & 3 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 3   & 2 & 4\\
    2 & 7 & 10 & 11\\
    1 & 3 & 4 & 7}
\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1}.
$$
In this case, it turns out that it's easy to find that inverse (by row-reduction for instance) which turns out to be 
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1}^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{1&-1&0&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&1}
$$